# How do I execute jQuery by clicking a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load a a new set of HTML dynamically and have a jQuery snippet to do this. How do I bind it on a click?

The jQuery:

```
$("body.page-ready").load("photo.html .test> *");
```

The link:

```
<li id="menu-item" class="menu-item-318"><a href="photo.html">Polaroids</a></li>
```

The link already loads a new page with the desired HTMl, but  I want it dynamically thought the above javascript. Can I Change the link to an anchor that execute the above jQuery code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this way:

```
<li id="menu-item" class="menu-item-318">
  <a href="photo.html"
    onclick='$("body.page-ready").load("photo.html .test> *"); return false;'>Polaroids</a>
</li>
```

Or in the unobtrusive way:

```
$(function () {
  $("#menu-item a").click(function () {
    $("body.page-ready").load("photo.html .test> *");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah that worked great - The first part is what I went for. I didn't even think of execute the script directly in the link.

Comment: @user3344734 But that's actually bad. So try the second one.

Comment: Ah ok. Ill try the other one. Thanks again!